# Just once I'd like a PB & PB

Tags: slang, abbreviations, terminology, food

Not sure if that has a special meaning but I heard it in a movie:

> Just once I’d like a PB & PB.

What does it mean?

Here is a cartoon:

[image]

Comment: One of those at least must be Peanut Butter.

Comment: And the other might be Personal Best.

Comment: People are always making [sandwiches out of peanut butter](http://www.cdkitchen.com/recipes/course/main-dish/sandwiches/peanut-butter-sandwich/) and other things: peanut butter and jelly; peanut butter and honey; peanut butter and Nutella; peanut butter and cheese; peanut butter and onion; peanut butter and bacon; peanut butter and pickles; peanut butter and marshmallow; peanut butter and tomato (with lettuce and mayo). Obviously somebody thought it would be good to have a sandwich with peanut butter on one piece of bread combined with peanut butter on the other slice for a change.

Comment: I think tchrist is right. The quote sounds like a (would-be) laugh line premised on the idea that a "peanut butter and peanut butter" sandwich sounds funny. The term _PB&J_ (for "peanut butter and jelly" has become as common as _BLT_ ("bacon, lettuce, and tomato") as a sandwich designation in these precincts.

Comment: Of course, since the poster heard the line in a movie, it's possible that the script actually says "PB & Pb"—that is, "peanut butter and lead."

Comment: I forgot the ever-popular *peanut butter and potato chip* sandwich. Perhaps the second PB stands for *potato biscuits* or something: you know, like gaufrettes.

Comment: @SvenYargs: Only an ancient Roman would put lead salt on a peanut butter sandwich.

Comment: http://www.andertoons.com/food/cartoon/4505/just-once-id-like-pb-and-pb/
@tchrist Peanut butter and Phenobarbital

Answer (score 4):

### PB&PB

PB & PB is a play on PB & J, which according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peanut_butter_and_jelly_sandwich):

> The **peanut butter and jelly sandwich** or **PB&J** is a sandwich, popular in North America, that includes a layer of peanut butter and either jelly or jam on bread, commonly between two slices, but sometimes eaten open-faced or with one slice folded over.

"Just once I’d like a PB & PB" means the speaker is sick and tired of PB&Js and would like a peanut butter sandwich without the jam.

### *OED* PB&J

The earliest example of PB & J (also P.B. and J., PB and J, P.B. & J. and with lower-case initials) in the Oxford English Dictionary is:

> 1973   *Times Recorder* (Zanesville, Ohio) 16 Aug. 3 c/5   Many mothers work and must leave a snack in the refrigerator, PB and J being the easiest.

But slightly antedated by PBJ:

> 1971   *Post-Standard* (Syracuse, N.Y.) 9 Mar. 5/5   No more PBJ sandwiches.

### PB&J antedatings

**1967**

I found some antedatings. First, on page 78 of [*Generation* magazine](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=P_AcAAAAMAAJ&pg=RA2-PA78&dq=%22peanut%20butter%20*%20jelly%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=5EoLUoaII-jL4ATvj4DwAw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22peanut%20butter%20and%20jelly%22&f=false) (1967, volume XIX, number 1) in a play called "The Machine" by Fritz Lyon:

[image: SECOND MAN. (Tastes his p.pb &j. sandwich, winces) I haven't had peanut butter and jelly in a long time, either.]

**1969 & 1970**

There's some possible 1969-1971 antedatings in *Trail and Timberline* (Issues 601-636), but as only snippets are shown, the date may be wrong. The [Hathitrust catalogue record](http://catalog.hathitrust.org/Record/009964732) says these issues are from 1969-1971.

Page 84 (probably ["May 1969"](http://books.google.co.uk/books?ei=ukgLUraCF4S04AS5u4GYBg&id=PRszAQAAIAAJ&dq=%22On%20the%20trail%20every%20day,%20With%20ample%20P%20B%20&%20J%22&q=%22may%201969%22#search_anchor), as found on [pages 73 - 103](http://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt/search?id=uc1.$b725763&view=1up&seq=5&q1=%22May%201969%22)):

> On the trail every day,
> With ample P B & J,
> Who knows, we may stay for a month and two weeks.

Page 181 (probably ["September 1970"](http://books.google.co.uk/books?ei=ukgLUraCF4S04AS5u4GYBg&id=PRszAQAAIAAJ&dq=%22On%20the%20trail%20every%20day,%20With%20ample%20P%20B%20&%20J%22&q=%22september%201970%22#search_anchor), as found on [pages 181 - 269](http://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt/search?q1=%22September%201970%22&id=uc1.$b725763&view=1up&seq=5)):

> You'll never guess right on peanut butter and jelly, but take a lot. When all else fails, you can keep the crowd happy with P.B. & J.

### Sandwich history

Wikipedia gives this [history](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peanut_butter_and_jelly_sandwich#History):

> In the early 1900s, peanut butter was considered a delicacy that was only served in New York City's finest tearooms. The product was first paired with a diverse set of foods such as pimento, nasturtium, cheese, celery, watercress, and on toasted crackers. In a *Good Housekeeping* article published in May 1896, a recipe "urged homemakers to use a meat grinder to make peanut butter and spread the result on bread." In June of that same year, the culinary magazine *Table Talk* published a "peanut butter sandwich recipe." The first reference of peanut butter paired with jelly on bread to be published in the United States was by Julia Davis Chandler in 1901 in the Boston Cooking-School Magazine of Culinary Science and Domestic Economics. By the late 1920s, this sandwich eventually moved down the class structure as the price of peanut butter dropped. It became popular with children. During World War II, it is said that both peanut butter and jelly were found on U.S. soldiers' military ration list, as claimed by the Peanut Board.

The *[New York Times Magazine](http://www.nytimes.com/packages/html/magazine/2013/innovations-issue/#/?part=pbj)* quotes Julia Davis Chandler as the earliest reference to peanut butter and jelly in November 1901:

> ‘‘Try making little sandwiches . . . of three very thin layers of bread and two of filling, one of peanut paste, whatever brand you prefer, and currant or crab-apple jelly,’’ Julia Davis Chandler wrote in November 1901 in The Boston Cooking- School Magazine of Culinary Science and Domestic Economics. ‘‘The combination is delicious, and, so far as I know, original.’’ This is the earliest reference to peanut butter and jelly, and it appeared before the ingredients were widely available — you might have had to grind your own peanuts. It would be a while before the sandwich became a hit among those it’s most associated with: children. That happened later, after peanut butter became available in jars in supermarkets and was marketed to children in the 1930s. (The invention of sliced and packaged bread in 1928 also increased the sandwich’s popularity.) Jon Krampner, the author of ‘‘Creamy & Crunchy,’’ a history of peanut butter, says that PB&J satisfies three American desires: it’s sweet, it’s nutritious and it’s quick. That combination of qualities might be what prompted New York board of education officials, through a W.P.A. project in the late 1930s, to provide peanut butter and jelly sandwiches as part of a free-lunch program in schools.

### Peanut butter and jelly antedatings

I found a slightly earlier reference in the 29th June 1901 *Evening Star* (page 19, image 19, Washington, D.C.), in the "Table and Kitchen" column on ["Sandwiches for Picnics and Outdoor Functions"](http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn83045462/1901-06-29/ed-1/seq-19/#date1=1836&sort=date&date2=1922&searchType=advanced&language=&sequence=0&index=0&words=jam+Peanuts+raspberry+strawberry&proxdistance=5&rows=20&ortext=&proxtext=&phrasetext=peanuts+and+strawberry+or+raspberry+jam&andtext=&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=1):

> Peanut Sandwich.
>
> These are quite popular and are to be recommended for children's luncheons and picnic parties. If possible they should be served at once, as soon as made; cover thin slices of white bread with a stiff mayonnaise dressing; cover this well with ground peanuts which have been well roasted or salted and chopped fine. When served at society luncheons they should be accompanied with sherry. For children's luncheons or picnics put the roasted nuts through a meat grinder and spread the paste on buttered slices of bread. Mixed nuts can be used. **Peanuts and strawberry or raspberry jam** make a delicious, sweet sandwich for tea, and is better for children than sweet cake.

Comment: I've sent the PB&J antedatings to the OED.